# How do you update a pointer that has to go through 3 functions?

Tags: c, pointers

Let's say I have a pointer inside `function1`, I need to pass it to `function2`, and `function2` needs to pass it to `function3`, `function3` needs to update that pointer. How do you correctly do this?

Do you use triple stars? If so, what's the correct way to pass the pointer inside `function2`?

```
function1(void){
    char *pointer;
    function2(&pointer)
}

function2(char **pointer){
      function3(&(*pointer));
}

function3(char ***pointer)}
    /*update pointer*/
}
```

My question is specifically about this situation only (3 functions), I don't want to remove `function2`, even if it does nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just keep two levels of pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int b = 42;

void foo(int **a) {
    *a = &b;
}

void bar(int **a) {
    foo(a);
    printf("%d\n", **a);
    **a = 21;
}

int main()
{
    int *a = NULL;

    bar(&a);

    printf("%d\n", *a);
}
```

Output:

```
42
21
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Would it work with a linked list? Where `*a` is the head, and `foo` is the `insert`. Or would it cause memory leaks?

Comment: @MichaelX This should work, feel free to search example of implementation of linked list, there are many ways. [This example](http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists) is not very good because they don't check error, but this suit your wish.

Comment: I know how to implement one. But I've always put the head inside main, and then called insert from there, I've never tried to make the head go through a function in-between main and insert.